# How can I make this function take dynamic values?

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

I have created a function to test a input field, the function currently accepts 6 inputs, 3 of them are text to be typed and the other 3 are error messages that we get when certain text is typed, this works fine. The function will loop depending on the number of texts entered, so in this case it will enter text and then click submit and then check error message. It will do this 3 times because I am passing in 3 text values. However I want to be able to make it dynamic so that it can take any number values and loop according to however many are passed.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('checkErrMsg', (fieldText1, fieldText2, fieldText3, errorText1,errorText2, errorText3) => { 
var fieldValues = [fieldText1, fieldText2, fieldText3];
var errorValues = [errorText1, errorText2, errorText3];
var sum =0;

fieldValues.forEach(function(entry) {
    cy.get('.textBox').clear().type(entry)
    cy.get('.addBtn').click()
    cy.get('#errMsg').should('be.visible').and('have.contain',(errorValues[sum++])).click();
});
})
```

I add the custom command to namespace as required by typescript project in cyprss.

```
declare namespace Cypress {
interface Chainable {
    checkErrMsg(fieldText1: string, fieldText2: string, fieldText3:string, errorText1:string
    ,errorText2: string, errorText3:string): Chainable<string>;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to make this kind of variadic function is with a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters). The tricky part is that you need two - one for the fields, one for the errors - if you have each of them as a separate argument. One option is a `[string, string]` tuple type for each pair of field and error. The declaration would look like this:

```js
declare namespace Cypress {
    type FieldAndErrorValues = [string, string];
    interface Chainable {
        checkErrMsg(...fieldAndErrorValues: FieldAndErrorValues[]): Chainable<string>;
    }
}
```

And the implementation:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('checkErrMsg', (...fieldAndErrorValues: Cypress.FieldAndErrorValues[]) => { 
    fieldAndErrorValues.forEach(function([fieldValue, errorValue]) {
        cy.get('.textBox').clear().type(fieldValue);
        cy.get('.addBtn').click();
        cy.get('#errMsg').should('be.visible').and('have.contain',(errorValue)).click();
    });
});
```

And a possible invocation:

```js
cy.checkErrMsg(['field1', 'error1'], ['field2', 'error2']);
```